# iOS issue in background location updates. It stops after around 24 hours

Tags: ios

In my app I want to fetch and upload location on server in regular intervals. for foreground it works fine but for background it has issue as described below. One thing to mention here I use different class for foreground and separate code for background.

To fetch location in background I do the following. It does upload location for about 24 - 40 hours but get stopped after 24-40 hours. I did not get "willTerminate" event. I have also written code to capture global execption so that I could log SigKill if user kill my app but it too does not get logged reason could be we can't catch SigKill.

Now I am stuck don't know what to do to keep my app alive in background to upload location in regular intervals.

//////////////////////////////// **didfinish lauch** ///////////////////////////////

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 

{

     self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    return YES;

}


////////// **did enter background**


- (void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application

{


         self.bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{


        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.bgTask];
        self.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];


       timer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:8*60
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(changeAccuracy)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES] retain];
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];



}

- (void) changeAccuracy 

{

    self.bCallbackStarted = NO;
   [self.locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

    [self.locationManager setDistanceFilter:100];
}


///////// **did enter fore ground**

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application

{
 [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

}

////////// **did update location**
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)lm didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations

{

    if (self.bCallbackStarted == YES) {
        NSString* logStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"URLFilteringAppDelegate::didUpdateLocations not uploading location because self.bCallbackStarted == YES"];
        LOGI(logStr)
        return;
    }
    self.bCallbackStarted = YES;
    [[AppUtility sharedInstance] setLocationStatus:YES];
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];



    if(location.coordinate.latitude == 0 && location.coordinate.longitude == 0)
    {
        [UserSettings sharedInstance].Latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"Unavailable"];

        [UserSettings sharedInstance].Longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"Unavailable"];

    }
    else
    {
        [UserSettings sharedInstance].Latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", location.coordinate.latitude];
         [UserSettings sharedInstance].Longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", location.coordinate.longitude];
    }



    [[LocationManager sharedInstance] sendLocation];

     /// this is set to save battery

    [lm setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers];
    [lm setDistanceFilter:99999];

}
```

Comment: When your app moves to the background switch to significant location updates. This does not require you to establish a background task and is better for battery life. Your app will receive location updates indefinitely

Comment: Right but what is wrong with this logic? or What is the possible reason for this?

Comment: you cannot keep your app alive in the background indefinitely using background tasks - eventually iOS will unload your app. With significant location changes, iOS will relaunch your app if necessary